# How to use PayPal's SDK(Java or JavaScript) to achieve Allow for Order Completion in Two or Fewer Steps?

Tags: javascript, java, paypal

I want to implement this function :

PayPal Checkout

Allow for Order Completion in Two or Fewer Steps

[quick-order-completion](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/best-practices/quick-order-completion)

I tried :

1.1 [Set up a Transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/)

1.2 [Capture Transaction Funds](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/capture-transaction/)

2.1 [Set up an Authorization Transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction-authorize/)

2.2 [Create an Authorization](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/authorize-transaction/)

2.3 [Capture an Authorization](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/capture-authorization/)

But all are direct payments !

```java
@Service
public class AuthorizationService {

    @Autowired
    private PayPalClient payPalClient;

    //2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
    /**
     *Method to create order
     *
     *@param debug true = print response data
     *@return HttpResponse<Order> response received from API
     *@throws IOException Exceptions from API if any
     */
    public com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject createOrder(boolean debug) throws IOException {
        OrdersCreateRequest request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
        request.prefer("return=representation");
        request.requestBody(buildCreateOrderRequestBody());
        //3. Call PayPal to set up the transaction
        HttpResponse<Order> response = payPalClient.client().execute(request);
        if (debug) {
            if (response.statusCode() == 201) {
                System.out.println("Status Code: " + response.statusCode());
                System.out.println("Status: " + response.result().status());
                System.out.println("Order ID: " + response.result().id());
                System.out.println("Intent: " + response.result().intent());
                System.out.println("Links: ");
                for (LinkDescription link : response.result().links()) {
                    System.out.println("\t" + link.rel() + ": " + link.href() + "\tCall Type: " + link.method());
                }
                System.out.println("Total Amount: " + response.result().purchaseUnits().get(0).amount().currencyCode()
                        + " " + response.result().purchaseUnits().get(0).amount().value());
            }
        }

        Order order = response.result();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new Json().serialize(order));
        com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject result = com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject.parseObject(json.toString(4));
        return result;
    }

    /**
     *Method to generate sample create order body with AUTHORIZE intent
     *
     *@return OrderRequest with created order request
     */
    private OrderRequest buildCreateOrderRequestBody() {
        OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest();
        orderRequest.intent("AUTHORIZE");

        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ApplicationContext().brandName("EXAMPLE INC").landingPage("BILLING")
                .shippingPreference("SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS");
        orderRequest.applicationContext(applicationContext);

        List<PurchaseUnitRequest> purchaseUnitRequests = new ArrayList<PurchaseUnitRequest>();
        PurchaseUnitRequest purchaseUnitRequest = new PurchaseUnitRequest().referenceId("PUHF")
                .description("Sporting Goods").customId("CUST-HighFashions").softDescriptor("HighFashions")
                .amount(new AmountWithBreakdown().currencyCode("USD").value("230.00")
                        .breakdown(new AmountBreakdown().itemTotal(new Money().currencyCode("USD").value("180.00"))
                                .shipping(new Money().currencyCode("USD").value("30.00"))
                                .handling(new Money().currencyCode("USD").value("10.00"))
                                .taxTotal(new Money().currencyCode("USD").value("20.00"))
                                .shippingDiscount(new Money().currencyCode("USD").value("10.00"))))
                .items(new ArrayList<Item>() {
                    {
                        add(new Item().name("T-shirt").description("Green XL").sku("sku01")
                                .unitAmount(new Money().currencyCode("USD").value("90.00"))
                                .tax(new Money().currencyCode("USD").value("10.00")).quantity("1")
                                .category("PHYSICAL_GOODS"));
                        add(new Item().name("Shoes").description("Running, Size 10.5").sku("sku02")
                                .unitAmount(new Money().currencyCode("USD").value("45.00"))
                                .tax(new Money().currencyCode("USD").value("5.00")).quantity("2")
                                .category("PHYSICAL_GOODS"));
                    }
                })
                .shipping(new ShippingDetails().name(new Name().fullName("John Doe"))
                        .addressPortable(new AddressPortable().addressLine1("123 Townsend St").addressLine2("Floor 6")
                                .adminArea2("San Francisco").adminArea1("CA").postalCode("94107").countryCode("US")));
        purchaseUnitRequests.add(purchaseUnitRequest);
        orderRequest.purchaseUnits(purchaseUnitRequests);
        return orderRequest;
    }

    //2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
    /**
     *Method to authorize order after creation
     *
     *@param orderId Valid Approved Order ID from createOrder response
     *@param debug   true = print response data
     *@return HttpResponse<Order> response received from API
     *@throws IOException Exceptions from API if any
     */
    public com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject authorizeOrder(String orderId, boolean debug) throws IOException {
        OrdersAuthorizeRequest request = new OrdersAuthorizeRequest(orderId);
        request.requestBody(buildAuthorizeOrderRequestBody());
        // 3. Call PayPal to authorization an order
        HttpResponse<Order> response = payPalClient.client().execute(request);
        // 4. Save the authorization ID to your database. Implement logic to save the authorization to your database for future reference.
        if (debug) {
            System.out.println("Authorization Ids:");
            response.result().purchaseUnits()
                    .forEach(purchaseUnit -> purchaseUnit.payments()
                            .authorizations().stream()
                            .map(authorization -> authorization.id())
                            .forEach(System.out::println));
            System.out.println("Link Descriptions: ");
            for (LinkDescription link : response.result().links()) {
                System.out.println("\t" + link.rel() + ": " + link.href());
            }
            System.out.println("Full response body:");
            System.out.println(new JSONObject(new Json().serialize(response.result())).toString(4));
        }

        Order order = response.result();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new Json().serialize(order));
        com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject result = com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject.parseObject(json.toString(4));
        return result;
    }

    /**
     *Building empty request body.
     *
     *@return OrderActionRequest with empty body
     */
    private OrderActionRequest buildAuthorizeOrderRequestBody() {
        return new OrderActionRequest();
    }

    //2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
    /**
     * Method to patch order
     *
     * @throws IOException Exceptions from API, if any
     */
    public com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject patchOrder(String orderId) throws IOException {
        OrdersPatchRequest request = new OrdersPatchRequest(orderId);
        request.requestBody(buildRequestBody());
        payPalClient.client().execute(request);
        OrdersGetRequest getRequest = new OrdersGetRequest(orderId);
        //3. Call PayPal to patch the transaction
        HttpResponse<Order> response = payPalClient.client().execute(getRequest);
        System.out.println("After Patch:");
        System.out.println("Order ID: " + response.result().id());
        System.out.println("Intent: " + response.result().intent());
        System.out.println("Links: ");
        for (LinkDescription link : response.result().links()) {
            System.out.println("\t" + link.rel() + ": " + link.href() + "\tCall Type: " + link.method());
        }
        System.out.println("Gross Amount: " + response.result().purchaseUnits().get(0).amount().currencyCode() + " "
                + response.result().purchaseUnits().get(0).amount().value());
        System.out.println("Full response body:");
        System.out.println(new JSONObject(new Json().serialize(response.result())).toString(4));

        Order order = response.result();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new Json().serialize(order));
        com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject result = com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject.parseObject(json.toString(4));
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Method to create body for patching the order.
     *
     * @return List<Patch> list of patches to be made
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private List<Patch> buildRequestBody() throws IOException {
        List<Patch> patches = new ArrayList<>();
//        patches.add(new Patch().op("replace").path("/intent").value("CAPTURE"));
        patches.add(new Patch().op("replace").path("/purchase_units/@reference_id=='PUHF'/amount")
                .value(new AmountWithBreakdown().currencyCode("USD").value("250.00")
                        .breakdown(new AmountBreakdown().itemTotal(new Money().currencyCode("USD").value("180.00"))
                                .shipping(new Money().currencyCode("USD").value("50.00"))
                                .handling(new Money().currencyCode("USD").value("10.00"))
                                .taxTotal(new Money().currencyCode("USD").value("20.00"))
                                .shippingDiscount(new Money().currencyCode("USD").value("10.00")))));
        return patches;
    }

}
```

I want :

1. Login PayPal
2. Select shipping address
3. Go back my website and return user's shipping address
4. Calculate shipping based on shipping address
5. Update payment amount
6. Pay

Answer (score 0):

I found : https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_HK/developer/docs/pdf/hostedsolution_hk.pdf

[image]

[image]

Use [NVP/SOAP Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReference/#)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

The previous picture failed, and it was sent again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the methods in this document(Show a Confirmation Page) to achieve.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/confirmation-page/